# How to query to sum facts in prolog?

Tags: prolog

I'm completely new to prolog and can't figure out how to query the following, creating a small example of what I'm trying to do:

There is the set of facts:

```
calories(pizzaSlice, 250).
calories(porkFillet, 400).
```

I need to know *"How many calories do pizzaSlice and porkFillet have, together?"*

I feel like there should be a straight forward way to do this but I can't figure it out.

If I ask:

```
calories(pizzaSlice, X).
// X = 250 .
```

But I tried the following. All of them result in errors:

```
(calories(pizzaSlice, X) + calories(porkFillet, X)).
(calories(pizzaSlice, X) + calories(porkFillet, Y)).
(calories(pizzaSlice, _) + calories(porkFillet, _)).
```

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please remember that Prolog is a declarative programming language based on first order logic. You cannot write functions in Prolog that return a value (as for example in Python), you always define logical predicates.

The query for your example would be:

```
?- calories(pizzaSlice, CalPS), 
   calories(porkFillet, CalPF), 
   Sum is CalPS + CalPF.
```

The variable `Sum` will get instantiated by the sum of calories of `pizzaSlice` (which is `CalPS`) and `porkFillet`(which is `CalPF`).